# Need input on "seamless audio capturing on websites" - what is the state of the art?

Tags: javascript, html, audio-recording

The short version of my question is:

**How may I realize seamless audio capturing on a web-site and save it on the server?**

"seamless" means not having to use an external program for recording and afterwards uploading the file.

Few constraints:

1) **No Adobe** or other commercially licensed tools

2) Runs at least on Chrome or Firefox of most recent version (that means also **browser plug-ins** come into play for me!)

3) no java

I am wondering why this feature isn't yet realized for HTML5 as it is specified as far as I know and is a very desirable one for sure!?

I am a bit confused regarding this quote:

> Another area where Flash will remain is videoconferencing and recording audio or video. HTML5 has no method for controlling a user’s microphone or web cam. This means that Flash will continue to be used for conferencing applications and video chat programs.

http://www.jimcode.org/2011/07/html5-and-flash-why-flash-is-here-to-stay/

as it states that this feature isn't planned for HTML5!?

---

[YUI Theater — Scott Schiller: “Probably, Maybe, No: The State Of HTML5 Audio” (51 min.)](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2011/06/29/video-f2esummit2011-schiller/)

[Chrome 14 Beta Adds Native Client, Lion Support, *Web Audio*](http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2391006,00.asp)

[Speech Input API Specification](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-xg-htmlspeech/2011Feb/att-0020/api-draft.html)

[The Capture API - W3C Working Draft 01 April 2010](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-capture-api-20100401/)

[HTML Media Capture - W3C Working Draft 14 April 2011](http://www.w3.org/TR/capture-api/)

Comment: As far as I know, this is impossible with the limitations outlined by you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two methods of handling this

- [HTML5 Speech inputs](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-xg-htmlspeech/2011Feb/att-0020/api-draft.html#api_description)
- [WHATWG Real time communications](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/complete/video-conferencing-and-peer-to-peer-communication.html)

The HTML5 speech input is currently supported by [chrome](http://thenextweb.com/dd/2011/03/22/google-bringing-html5-speech-input-support-to-chrome/) (and maybe safari) as

`<input type="text" x-webkit-speech />`

In theory you can write a `webkit-speech` plugin for firefox and this would meet your chrome & firefox support criteria. In practice writing such a plugin is a *beast* of a job.

The [WebRTC](http://www.webrtc.org/) is supported by [chromium](http://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/group/chromium-dev/browse_thread/thread/95bf1e2e1de852fc) and is experimental

Also it turns out webkit has `navigator.webkitGetUserMedia` (which is defined in the [WHATWG specification](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/complete/video-conferencing-and-peer-to-peer-communication.html#dom-navigator-getusermedia)) but I can't get it to do anything. You might need chromium for it to do something

Answer (score 2):

The HTML 5 Device API is currently being developed, and it will allow native HTML/JavaScript access to input devices such as cameras and microphones.